# Is it possible to simplify (not solving) a system of differential equations with sympy?

Tags: sympy, differential-equations

I have systems of differential equations that have the following form (very very simple example):

1. f1(x)+A*f1'(x)-g1(f2(x))=0
2. f1(x)-B*f1'(x)-g2(f2(x))=0

A, B are sympy symbols, g1(x) and g2(x) are sympy expressions of a sympy function f2(x).

Does it exist a function in sympy that could **DIRECTLY** simplify this system and remove f1(x)) to obtain the following ODE :
g1(f2(x))+B*g1'(f2(x))-g2(f2(x))+A*g2(f2(x))=0 (that will be solved latter to obtain f2(x)) ?
I know how to create this differential equation on this simple system by coding directly the above formula. But, in the case of more complicated systems, it could be very tedious (higher derivative order and more differential equations)

To be more genreal, does it exist in sympy a function 
which takes the system of diff. eq. and the functions to keep/or remove as arguments 
and that ouputs a new system of diff. eq.

Thanks for answer.

Example added to answer at Oscar Benjamin comment.
Declaration of constants, fuctions and eq. diff. system

```
C, Cs, Rs, t = sp.symbols("C Cs Rs t",real=True)
U2a=sp.Function('U2a')(t)
U2=sp.Function('U2')(t)
i2=sp.Function('i2')(t)
i=sp.Function('i')(t)
eq1=sp.Eq(U2a-C*Rs*U2.diff(t,1)-U2+Rs*i2,0)
eq2=sp.Eq(U2a+Cs*Rs*U2a.diff(t,1)-U2-Rs*i,0)
```

Following the notations above and to remove U2a(t), definitions of g1, g2, A and B

```
g1=-C*Rs*U2.diff(t,1)-U2+Rs*i2
g2=-U2-Rs*i
A=0
B=Cs*Rs
```

So, the new diff. eq. is :

```
dfSimp=sp.Eq(g1+B*g1.diff(t,1)-g2-A*g2.diff(t,1),0)
```

Comment: How exactly do you combine the two ODEs to get the one for f2?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin. Thanks for answer. I edited my question and I added an example

Comment: I still don't understand what the general manipulation you want to do is. It is not enough just to give an example since you are saying that you already know how to solve the example. There is some general problem that you want to solve and you need to state it in general terms along with the restrictions that are need to make it solvable in general.